# Projecting IQueryable leads to SQL Server throwing exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, projection

I am using Automapper's queryable extension's `ProjectTo` to query my EF Core 6 entities based the DTO class queryable. The entities are quite large objects graphs, but the projection has been working well. Except for one entity.

Depending on the resulting filtered data (so this dependent on the returned data), EF Core receives an error message from SQL Server:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot create a row of size 8310 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

Important to note: the whole database is created by code first data migrations (EF Core 3.1 onwards). I did rebuild all tables with `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foos] REBUILD`  just to be sure.

When I execute the query directly against the entity (so not projecting from the DTO class), the issue does not surface.

What could the projection configuration do to cause this?

```c
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public List<Baz> Bazs { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //... Other properties and collections
}

public class Baz
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    //... Other properties and collections
}

// Projection
IQueryable<FooDTO> foosQuery = dbContext.Foos
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ProjectTo<FooDTO>(mapperConfiguration);
```

Using below projection configuration will throw the exception on execution:

```c
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateProjection<Foo, FooDTO>();
    cfg.CreateProjection<Bar, BarDTO>();
    cfg.CreateProjection<Baz, BazDTO>();
});
```

This configuration fails as well:

```c
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateProjection<Foo, FooDTO>();
    cfg.CreateProjection<Bar, BarDTO>()
        // Ignore all properties individually like this:
        .ForMember(x => x.Description, opt => opt.Ignore());
    cfg.CreateProjection<Baz, BazDTO>();
});
```

This however does not fail:

```c
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateProjection<Foo, FooDTO>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Bars, opt => opt.Ignore());
    cfg.CreateProjection<Bar, BarDTO>();
    cfg.CreateProjection<Baz, BazDTO>();
});
```

And the below query against the entity also does not fail:

```c
IQueryable<Foo> foosQuery = dbContext.Foos
    .Include(x => x.Bars).Include(x => x.Bazs).AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: The last not failing query is not equivalent though. How about `dbContext.Foos.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Bars).Include(x => x.Bazs)`? Should fail as well. Looks like you have too many string (`nvarchar(max)`) columns. Try adding `AsSplitQuery()` and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks: I had missed it in my abstraction, but the actual code did have the properties included in the query on the entity.

Comment: As to having too many `nvarchar(max)` columns, is this not monitored by EF Core?  I count 26 columns of that type, in addition to columns of other types.  But then again: wouldn't the query with the entity (which logically is the same table) throw the same exception?

Comment: Initial testing shows `.AsSplitQuery()` solves the problem!  

Comment: It's not just that table. Single query mode (the default) will create query containing all selected columns from Foo + all selected from Bar + all selected from Baz. EF Core cannot track that, moreover this is a specific SqlServer limitation. Split query will execute 3 SQL queries containing only the selected columns from the corresponding tables.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I have self answered the question, but if you prefer to submit the answer then I will accept that answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the guidance of (the always helpful and knowledgeable!) Ivan Stoev, the issue was resolved by splitting the query using `AsSplitQuery`.

> Single query mode (the default) will create query containing all selected columns from Foo + all selected from Bar + all selected from Baz. EF Core cannot track that, moreover this is a specific SqlServer limitation. Split query will execute 3 SQL queries containing only the selected columns from the corresponding tables.

```c
// Projection
IQueryable<FooDTO> foosQuery = dbContext.Foos
    .AsNoTracking()
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ProjectTo<FooDTO>(mapperConfiguration);
```